# GPS coordinates from Unity

Tags: c#, gps, android-gps, unity-game-engine

How do I get my current GPS coordinates via my Unity app?

I'm using the following code (I also tried https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LocationService.Start.html) but both sets of code are making my app crash; I think it's from  `Input.Location.Start()` or somewhere near maxWait.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GPSCtrl : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Text distance_label;
    public GameObject distanceObject;

    void Start ()
    {
        distance_label = distanceObject.GetComponent<Text> ();
        distance_label.text = "0";

        StartCoroutine (StartLocationService ());
    }

    IEnumerator StartLocationService ()
    {
        // First, check if user has location service enabled
        if (!Input.location.isEnabledByUser)
            //yield break;
            distance_label.text = "Not initialized";

        // Start service before querying location
        Input.location.Start ();



        // Wait until service initializes
        int maxWait = 20;
        while (Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Initializing && maxWait > 0) {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (1);
            maxWait--;
        }

        // Service didn't initialize in 20 seconds
        if (maxWait < 1) {
            distance_label.text = "Timed out";
            //yield break;
        }


        // Connection has failed
        if (Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Failed) {
            distance_label.text = "Unable to determine device location";
            //yield break;
        } else {
            // Access granted and location value could be retrieved
            distance_label.text = "Location: " + Input.location.lastData.latitude + " " +
            Input.location.lastData.longitude + " " +
            Input.location.lastData.altitude + " " +
            Input.location.lastData.horizontalAccuracy + " " +
            Input.location.lastData.timestamp;
        }

        // Stop service if there is no need to query location updates continuously
        Input.location.Stop ();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Unity5.5.0 or 5.5.1? It has an issue where app instantly crashes when using Input.Location.Start(); Check out this link for more info: https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/android-location-app-crashes-due-to-error-jstring-has-wrong-type-android-dot-location-dot-location

Comment: @GuardingMallet Thanks. I'm using 5.5.1. Looks like I just need to download the patch or something...